# Consuming laravel api by angular

Tags: angularjs, api, laravel-5

Im working on a laravel 5 / angular 1 application ! 
I wanted to use database infos in my app but I get them under a json format in the view ! 
Here's the angular controller :

```
angular
.module('alerts')
.controller('alertscontroller', function($scope,$http){
$scope.alerts = [];
$http.get('{{ url('resident.alerts') }}').success(function ($data) {
              $scope.alerts = $data;
                            });
});
```

and here's is my laravel view

```
<div class="container" ng-app="alerts" ng-controller="alertscontroller">
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>User X</h3>
    <p><strong>Title : </strong>@{{ alert.title }}</p>
    <p><strong>Type : </strong>@{{ alert.type }}</p>
    <p><strong>Description : </strong>@{{ alert.description }}</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what I get as a result is the following

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Title1","description":"descriptionk,","type":"opel","status":0,"user_id":0,"created_at":"2016-08-20 21:41:00","updated_at":"2016-08-20 21:41:00"},{"id":2,"title":"Title1","description":"descriptionk,","type":"opel","status":0,"user_id":0,"created_at":"2016-08-20 21:44:05","updated_at":"2016-08-20 21:44:05"},{"id":3,"title":"Title1","description":"descriptionk,","type":"opel","status":0,"user_id":0,"created_at":"2016-08-20 21:51:54","updated_at":"2016-08-20 21:51:54"},{"id":4,"title":"Im stuck in the elevator","description":"the elevator stoped in the fourth floor when I was getting to the second floor, please help me","type":"other things","status":0,"user_id":0,"created_at":"2016-08-21 15:06:41","updated_at":"2016-08-21 15:06:41"},{"id":5,"title":"Im stuck in the elevator","description":"the elevator stoped in the fourth floor when I was getting to the second floor, please help me","type":"other things","status":0,"user_id":0,"created_at":"2016-08-21 15:08:34","updated_at":"2016-08-21 15:08:34"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault ! in the routes section, I had :                   `Route::get('resident.alerts', ['uses'=>alertsController@index', 'as'=>'resident.alerts']);` and the index method in the alertsControllers returns the alerts (return Alert::all() ) ! That's the reason behind the result I got !